# Как рендерить объекты с рандомным расположением, но чтобы они не пересекались при этом?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Я загружаю 20 3D-объектов.  Расположение у них рандомное каждый раз. Как мне сделать так, чтобы они также располагались рандомно, но не пересекались при этом? Как проверять, пересекаются ли объекты. Если да, то нужно их каким-то образом отодвигать друг от друга

Вот код

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // Create a material
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var map = textureLoader.load('./models/test_2.png');
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: map });

        var shipMtl = new MTLLoader();
        var loader = new this.THREE.OBJLoader();

        shipMtl.load('./models/test.mtl', function(materials) {
            materials.preload();

            loader.setMaterials(materials);
            loader.load('./models/test.obj', function(object) {
                object.traverse(function(node) {
                    if (node.isMesh) node.material = material;
                });

                object.position.x = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                var obj = object; // put your object as global
                scene.add(obj);
            });
        });
    }

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.refs.figure.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: А какого рода у вас объекты (примитивы или сложной формы) - приложите скриншот?

Comment: Интереса ради: зачем 20 раз загружать один и тот же объект, если можно загрузить его один раз и потом 20 раз в цикле клонировать в новой позиции? Поводу пересечения: можно проверять пересечение за счет рассчитанных `.boundingBox` или `.boundingSphere` у объектов.

Comment: Объекты сложной формы. 3D/ Есть куб, есть сфера, есть объекты сложной формы. В коде пока что 20 одинаковых объектов(кубы), но затем планирую сделать разные.